# Basic Question, Need Help: I can't figure out how to add a border vector?

Tags: css, border

I can not figure this one out. The border is attached as such, but whenever I try and load it, it either doesn't come up, or it looks completely different. All the CSS styles I've found round, stretch, transparent etc all sound great but keep tampering with the image- all I need is the the border as is on the topish-center of the orange of the page. It's probably a very simple thing but I have literally been going at this for *hours* and it is just not working. ><;;

How It Currently Looks (nvm it's on the wrong spot on the page): 
[image]

Full Border/What it Should Look Like (note am shrinking it by at least 50% to fit): 
[image]

The Code:

```css
<style>
  #border {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border-image: url(vborder.png) 30 round;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="border">
    <h2>hello</h2>
    <p>this is text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you, all!! ^^

Comment: don't add another question into your question if the first one is solved. Consider adding a new question. The intial question should remain as it is or the answer given will be irrelevant

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ooh thank you!! I see that now, nobody else seems to be asking multiple questions in a post ><; I was actually able to figure out the alignment code from help from other forums on here- so all is a good now! thank you for letting me know, I'll be more careful in future posts ;p

Answer (score 0):

I think the border-image you are using here is too large. As I can see the image is in `2550x3300` in px. Which is too large for a border image.

I increased the border width and that the border-image is shown now. But I don't think this is what you want. You may checkout this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/dyyOrMO).

Try scaling down the image in any image editor and try your existing code again :)

=======================================================================

**EDIT:**
I went checking out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice), you may actually keep the image size (which is bad for webpage size, you should scale down the image for a smaller file size). Using the property of `border-image-slice`, you can directly scale the border-image with CSS.

PS: I do think `border: 10px` is too thin for this border-image.

Comment: Ooh thank you, @blackcityhenry ! I'm not sure what happened, but I just adjusted the height and width to pixels and messed around some with the border sizing like you said (moved it up to 24px) and now it looks good as new!! Thank you for rewriting it for me!! I agree it should probably be scaled down but whenever I try to compress in Paint or Paint 3D it takes way the transparency, so I'm not too sure what to do about that? I think it's ok as is tho (even tho it's not as professional?)- it's just for neocities not anything rl. :D

Comment: Glad that you have figured your way to do so. 
For scaling images, I usually use GIMP(https://www.gimp.org/). On tool bar, 'Image' > 'Scale Image...'. After that, 'File' > 'Export...'. Then you're good to go :)

Comment: Oh COOL, thank you!!! that solves it. I'll go ahead and use that one then!! :D