# How can I have border-radius without anti-aliasing?

Tags: css, antialiasing

I want to make div corners pixelated when they have border-radius by increasing `scale()` value, but browsers make them smooth, is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Divs in the browser I think are vector so never degrade, but you could use a css border image to add some roughness. Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479481/basic-question-need-help-i-cant-figure-out-how-to-add-a-border-vector

Comment: try css `background-clip: padding-box;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to pixelate divs as they would be drawn using vectors. But with some clever CSS you can clip the borders. Check out Luke Bonaccorsi's [Pixelated Rounded Corners](https://pixelcorners.lukeb.co.uk/) tool.

Here is the outcome of his tool

```css
.pixel-corners {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;


  /** Luke Bonaccorsi's Pixelated Rounded Corners **/

  clip-path: polygon(
    0px 20px,
    4px 20px,
    4px 12px,
    8px 12px,
    8px 8px,
    12px 8px,
    12px 4px,
    16px 4px,
    20px 4px,
    20px 0px,
    calc(100% - 20px) 0px,
    calc(100% - 20px) 4px,
    calc(100% - 12px) 4px,
    calc(100% - 12px) 8px,
    calc(100% - 8px) 8px,
    calc(100% - 8px) 12px,
    calc(100% - 4px) 12px,
    calc(100% - 4px) 16px,
    calc(100% - 4px) 20px,
    100% 20px,
    100% calc(100% - 20px),
    calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 20px),
    calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 12px),
    calc(100% - 8px) calc(100% - 12px),
    calc(100% - 8px) calc(100% - 8px),
    calc(100% - 12px) calc(100% - 8px),
    calc(100% - 12px) calc(100% - 4px),
    calc(100% - 16px) calc(100% - 4px),
    calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 4px),
    calc(100% - 20px) 100%,
    20px 100%,
    20px calc(100% - 4px),
    12px calc(100% - 4px),
    12px calc(100% - 8px),
    8px calc(100% - 8px),
    8px calc(100% - 12px),
    4px calc(100% - 12px),
    4px calc(100% - 16px),
    4px calc(100% - 20px),
    0px calc(100% - 20px)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="pixel-corners">Pixel Corners</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much!